# How to configure submodule remote and push

Tags: github, git-submodules, git-commit, git-clone, git-remote

I have a third party repo as a submodule `sub` living in `parent/data/`.
In `parent/data/sub/`, `git status` gives me

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Apparently, I've made changes to the submodule and my local commit is recognised but has not pushed. Because the `remote` is `origin/master`, the third party repo, I get permission denied if I simply `git push`. However, pushing my customised and local changes to the original third party is not my goal anyway, as I only intend to customise the code so that I can use in my `parent` project.
Also, `git show HEAD` gives a hash `abc123` (made dummy for illustration purpose) and the correct changes that I've made.

Under `parent/`, `git submodule status` gives me

```
abc123 data/sub (heads/master)
```

and `vim .gitmodules` gives me

```
[submodule "data/sub"]
    path = data/sub
    url = https://github.com/owner-id/sub
```

everything seems fine to me. The obvious issue it seems is the non-pushed commit mentioned above. As a result, when I navigate to my repo online at `parent/data/sub@abc123` it shows 404. Meanwhile, when I try to `git clone https://github.com/my-id/parent.git --recurse-submodules` it shows

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: abc123
Unable to checkout 'abc123' in submodule path 'data/sub'
```

Question: how to push my local commits in `sub` to my own repo so that when others `clone` my `parent` the `parent/data/sub` is my customised version?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I forked a copy of the external repo and made that as the submodule. Apparently making changes to submodules so that everyone else can get the modified external repo is not the main use case of submodule, and it can't be done without forking first.